# Struct within another struct Solidity

Tags: solidity, remix

I just started learning solidity and I am working on a bidding contract that allows bidders to bid on a campaign. I have a struct for campaigns. Bidders have details (address, name), I want to store bidders with their information inside of the campaign. There can be more than one bidder for a campaign

This is my Campaign and Bidder struct

```
struct Campaign {
    uint256 campaignID;
    uint256 budget;
    uint256 bidCount;

}
 struct Bidder {
    bool bided;
    uint256 bid;
    string name;
    address bidderAddress;

}
mapping(address => Bidder) public bidders;
Campaign[] public campaigns;
```

I wrote down a bid function here that takes the index of campaign and bid then populate bidCount.

```
function bid(uint256 _bidIndex, uint256 _twitterID) public {
    require(!bidders[msg.sender].bided);

    bidders[msg.sender].bid = _bidIndex;
    campaigns[_bidIndex].bidCount += 1;
    totalBids += 1;
}
```

So the Campaign can look something like this (if this is possible)

```
0: campaignID 1
1: budget 2ETH
2: bidCount 3
3: Bidder {0: name Bidder1, 1: address 0xahaaahha}
          {0: name Bidder2, 2: address 0x2334jddd}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Example of struct array within a struct...

There can be multiple ActionData structs in an Operation (like you might have bidders in a campaign)

```
interface IWallet {
    struct Operation {
        uint256 nonce;
        IWallet.ActionData[] actions;
    }

    struct ActionData {
        uint256 ethValue;
        address contractAddress;
        bytes encodedFunction;
    }
    ...
}
```

(https://github.com/web3well/bls-wallet/blob/main/contracts/contracts/interfaces/IWallet.sol#L9-L18)